# How do I properly setup a RunLoop in Order to Unit Test NSURLConnection?

Tags: iphone, unit-testing

I'm using the unit testing tools provided in the Google Toolbox for Mac and I want to unit test some code involving NSURLConnections.  I believe I need to setup my own NSRunLoop if I want to be able to do this.

What is the proper way to setup such a run loop?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think to do that would be if you want to do a functional test of the actual asynchronous connection. That's going to be pretty fragile, and slow down your test bundle.

A better approach is to write unit tests of your implementations of [NSURLConnection's delegate methods](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html), like [connection:didFinishLoading:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/connectionDidFinishLoading:) (for success cases) and [connection:didFailWithError:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/connection:didFailWithError:) (for error cases)

I generally set up sample response values and verify that my delegate handles them correctly. For example:

```
    NSString *responseJSON = @"{\"remove\": [123,432], \"new\": [1,2]}";
    NSData *responseBytes = [responseJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // in requestHandler, data would have been set by calls to connection:didReceiveData:
    [requestHandler setData:responseBytes];

    [requestHandler connectionDidFinishLoading:nil];

    // set expectations here for what you'll do with the response
    ...
```